# How to make use of all CPU cores in Clojure

Tags: multithreading, concurrency, clojure

I have the following code:

```
(defn compile-report [id]
    (let [a (gen-first-part id)
          b (gen-second-part id)
          c (gen-third-part id)
          d (gen-fourth-part id)]

    (conj a b c d)))
```

Each of the 'gen-x-part' functions is cpu intensive. As I understand it, the let form will run these calculations in series on a single thread. If I had a single core machine there would be no point in running each on its own thread as they are all cpu-bound. However, I have a 4-core machine. How can I make use of each of these cores and dispatch each of these functions to its own core? thanks.

Comment: core-async can also use all the cores of your machine, without blocking.

Comment: @ChrisMurphy - how does it do that? Each thread can only process code sequentially and if it comes across (eg) an I/O bound function then that thread must surely block until the function returns.

Comment: Each go block will try to use a separate thread, and they will all be going at the same time. You can easily get your multi-core computer to 'max out' (use 100% of possible processing cycles), with the fan furiously spinning.

Comment: If a go block comes across an I/O bound function then sure it will be waiting for the response, but none of the other go blocks will be blocked. Also your code that is not in a go block will not be blocked. That's really what I meant by "without blocking".

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can wrap your CPU-intensive functions into [`future`](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/future)s:

```
(defn compile-report [id]
  (let [a (future (gen-first-part id))
        b (future (gen-second-part id))
        c (future (gen-third-part id))
        d (future (gen-fourth-part id))]

    (conj @a @b @c @d)))
```

It will make them run in separate threads. `@a` means `(deref a)` which will block until the result is available.

If your functions process bigger Clojure datasets, you might also take a look at [`pmap`](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/pmap).

Comment: thanks, so I am guessing that the JVM/OS will be clever enough to realise it has multi-cores and schedule the threads accordingly? Also, the final conj form is running in the main thread, so this whole thread blocks until all the futures return?

Comment: @user3231690 Yes to both questions.